# Why the compiler does not produce an error because the invariance of types is violated

Tags: java

An example is taken from the book Bruce Eckel's book
question in commentary

```
class GenericWriting{
static <T> void writeExact(List<T> list, T item) {
    list.add(item);
}
static List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<Apple>();
static List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
static void f1() {
    writeExact(apples, new Apple());
    writeExact(fruits, new Apple()); /* why the compiler does not produce an error because the invariance of types is violated */
}
static <T> void writeWithWildcard(List<? super T> list, T item) {
    list.add(item);
}
static void f2() {
    writeWithWildcard(apples, new Apple());
    writeWithWildcard(fruits, new Apple());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    f1();
    f2();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to polymorphism.

Normally, if you write such a method:

```
private static void method(Fruit f) {}
```

You can call it with a `new Apple()`:

```
method(new Apple());
```

right? Because `Apple` is a subclass of `Fruit`.

When you call your method:

```
writeExact(fruits, new Apple());
```

Since you did not explicitly specify `T`, the compiler tries to infer it. It sees that the first argument `fruits` is a `List<Fruit>`. It thinks that `T` must be `Fruit`. Now your method is like this:

```
static void writeExact(List<Fruit> list, Fruit item)
```

See? Passing an apple to the second parameter is completely fine since `Apple` is a subclass of `Fruit`.

On the other hand, if you specify the generic `T to be`Apple`, an error will occur:

```
List<Fruit> list = new ArrayList<>();
// compiler error!
GenericWriting.<Apple>writeExact(list, new Apple());
```

Because `List<Fruit>` is not compatible with `List<Apple>`.

Comment: GenericWriting. <Apple> writeExact (list, new Apple ());
<Apple> This means that now the method arguments should be exactly Apple?

Comment: You can explain the difference between
void m (T t)
and
void m (? t)
?

Comment: @SergiiGusar the ? thing is called "generic wildcard". Search for this on google or stack overflow to find out what it means. For example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html and regarding your first question, the method now becomes `(List<Apple>, Apple)` . You must pass a kind of `List<Apple>`, like `ArrayList<Apple>`, `List<Fruit>` won't work because of generic invariance.

Comment: @SergiiGusar If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!